# JavaScript Multiple tests

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTMl Web form with 12 groups of 11 input Combo boxes.

The first / default option in the first combo box in each group is "NO".

The user has the option to select "YES".

I want to run an initial test on this first combo box in each group, if the return value is YES (true) then I want to run further tests on the remaining 10 input boxes, if the test is false (The default value of "NO" then skip this group and test the first box in the next group.

I'm failing and i'm sure the answer is a simple one but I just can't work it out.

Please can someone help me with this.

```
if (UserRoomSelection_Room_01 == "YES") {

if (userFirstDayOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select First Day Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userFirstDateOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select First Date Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userFirstMonthOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select First Month Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userFirstYearOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select First Year Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userLastDayOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select Last Day Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userLastDateOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select Last Date Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userLastMonthOfBooking == "0") {
alert("Please Select Last Month Of Booking!");
    return false;
}
if (userLastYearOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select Last Year Of Booking!");
    return false;
}       
if (userBoard_Room_01 == "0") {
alert("Please Select Boarding!");
    return false;
}
if (!userRate_Room_01) {
alert("Please Enter The Rate For This Booking!");
    return false;
       }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what's your (representative/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?
Make sure to wrap it in a function and call the function using `return YourFunctionXXY();`

```
var ErrorMessage;
var AllOk=true;
    if (UserRoomSelection_Room_01 == "YES") {

        if (userFirstDayOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
        ErrorMessage+="Please Select First Day Of Booking!\n";
           AllOk=false;
        }
        if (userFirstDateOfBooking_Room_01 == "0") {
        ErrorMessage+="Please Select First Date Of Booking!\n";
           AllOk=false;
        }
        ........
    }
   if(UserRoomSelection_Room_02 == "YES"){
        .................... 
   }




        if(ErrorMessage!=""){
         alert(ErrorMessage);
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

return false; in your code interrupt any further execution. You can use flagging solution provided by Iesus Sonesson, but it's not a best practice to do so.

You have described algorithm, whis should be implemented using loop. For instance you can store your text messages and combos in array and then just iterate it.

```
for (var i in combos) {
    if(combos[i]['0'] == 'YES')
    {
        //iterate other combos
    } else {
        // go to next combo group
        break;     
    }
}
```